# apply same curve-color to tiff in batch in GIMP

Tags: colors, batch-processing, tiff, gimp, script-fu

I would like to apply a specific color curve to some 2000 .tif files.
I am a Windows user and so far I have used GIMP for photo editing.

Using Gimp 2.10 I was able to perform such task working on .JPG files using the batch Image Manipulation plug-in (bimp v 2.6; https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/).

Work flow so far for Jpegs in GIMP-2.10:

- Using  I created a color curve working on a jpg file (Colors-> curves).
- once happy with corrections I saved the curve in an external file ("myset") which hasbeen saved in '\User\appData\roaming\gimp\2.10\curves'
- using bimp plug in I choose Add->color correction
- in the new window that pop-up I then select only the checkbox "change the color curv from external file" (or similar, menus are not in english...sorry) and navigate to my "myset" curve file.
- finally run the batch

When I tried to do the same BUT WITH the .tif files, I got warnings of the kind "unknown filed tag  encountered" at the step of importing in bimp the images to process.

That said, I can open the individual tif files in Gimp (File -> open...).
When I do, I still get the warnings "unknown filed tag  encountered", but i can click "OK" on the message window and continue importing the file.

Now the "import TIFF" window show me a "Page 1" icon in the top part, then I can choose if opening the file as "levels" or "image". Both choices seem to give the same result.
At that point I can apply my "myset" curve to the file from the tool Colors-> curves.

One potential solution I've been thinking of is to write a script to do this and call it from the command line. I found something along that line here: https://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/11100-curves-spline-batch .
Unfortunately:

- I have no experience in writing script-fu scripts and very few on command line.
- looking at the example in the above link I cannot figure out how/where to point to the "myset" curve in the script.
- looking into the Procedure Brouser I do not know which is the one corresponding to the Color->curve tool. ( possibly someting like gimp-drawable-curves-splines, but again I dont know how to have that refer to "myset")

A copy of my "myset" curve and a some .tif esample files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RREt-WxdyqsGN5TaATwvPGl7_wnrU0Qi?usp=sharing).

Dows anyone have suggestion on perform batch curve color changes on these tif files similarly to what I describe for the jpg? I am open to other solution then GIMP (but for example I cannot open those tif in rawtherappe - don't know why - so that is less of an option)

IMPORTANT: the I need to preserve the tiff metadata (they're georeferenced)

Comment: `gimp-drawable-curves-splines` is indeed the adequate function; but you have to provide curves as a variables, it won't read the settings file for you but is is likely that the file contains exactly what is needed.

Comment: thanks. As an update, i did managed to use the bimp plugin on tif files. the problem i had was caused by the way I exported the images from the application that generated them. Indeed, they were exported as "tiled" tiff, and that caused the presence of pages in the files, which ultimately caused the plugin to crash.